# Webpack 4.8 and Babel 7 don't work after compiling in production

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

After compiling SPA (React) to production with NODE_ENV=production there is error:
n.e(...).then(...).config is not a function
n - Promise in UglifyJS

This is package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --colors",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server --mode production --env.NODE_ENV=production --colors",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --env.NODE_ENV=production --colors --optimize-minimize",
    "test": "test",
    "analyze:build": "cross-env ANALYZE=true npm run build",
    "analyze:start": "cross-env ANALYZE=true npm run start",
    "analyze:dev": "cross-env ANALYZE=true npm run dev"
  },
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": "last 2 versions"
      }
    }],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

webapack.config.js

```
entry: {
      app: [
        './index.js'
      ],
      core: [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'core-js',
        'react-router',
        'redux',
        'react-redux'
      ]
    },
optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          commons: {
            test: 'core',
            name: 'core',
            chunks: 'initial'
          },
          async: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            chunks: 'async',
            priority: -10
          },
          vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: "vendors",
            chunks: 'initial',
            priority: -20
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

dont know what im doing wrong =(

i was trying and with @babel/polyfill - same

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpeuM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries are not supported latest webpack.
Problem with with support .mjs files. So when you downgrade to version 3.x problem should be solved

Comment: Do you mean dev-server or webpack --mode development?